# Meaning of when a process in "ps -el" output does not show full path to executable?

Tags: terminal, command-line, path

On Catalina v10.15.7, I am using:

> ps -el

to investigate all running processes.

I have 430 running processes. Ignoring those associated with open terminals, I'd like to understand why these 6 processes do not have the full path to their executable file listed when using *ps -el*:
*aslmanager*, *auditd*, *autofsd*, *cloudphotod*, *endpointsecurityd*, *SafeEjectGPUAgent*

*aslmanager* and *auditd* are in */usr/sbin*, and yet */usr/sbin/syslogd*, */usr/sbin/notifyd*, and 31 other running processes from */usr/sbin* **do** have their full path listed in *ps -el* output.

*autofsd* and *endpointsecurityd* are both located in */usr/libexec*, yet 97 other running processes located in */usr/libexec* do have their full paths listed.

There seems to be aliasing going on with *cloudphotod* and *SafeEjectGPUAgent* for executable files in the context of *ps -el* output.

I'd like to learn anything about the *ps -el* output exceptions when full file paths are not displayed to the executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a case of output exceptions inside the `ps` command.

What `ps` does is that it lists all the processes - and in particular it prints out the first element of the so called `argv` for each process. By convention the first element contains the name of the executable - but it is not actually required to be that way.

Described roughly, when you for example start a program in the Terminal by typing this command:

```
/usr/bin/less document.txt
```

The shell (for example `zsh` or `bash`) will perform some variant of `exec()` to ask the operating system to run that process. `exec()` takes a number of parameters - namely first and foremost the path and name of the program to run (`/usr/bin/less`) - and a list of arguments for the program to process. The first argument is by convention the name of the program itself - and so the shell will usually put whatever you wrote to start the program in there. The second argument is "document.txt" in this example.

So with `less` running, you can run `ps -el` in another terminal, and you'll see the process and it will be listed as `/usr/bin/less`.

However, if you instead type this in the Terminal:

```
cd /usr/bin/
./less ~/document.txt
```

You'll find that running `ps -el` in another Terminal now lists the process as being simply `./less`.

So that's the reason why some programs lists a full path and some do not. It is simply because of how they were originally started.

If you now run